# SQL Server - update all data in all tables from backup

Tags: sql-server

I need to update data (all tables) on our QA environment by replacing it with our latest Prod Database data (Make QA more actual). As I understand, by default if I do it with SSMS it will also replace Security options and Roles which I want to avoid:

1. Our Prod and QA DBs are on different servers so service accounts regulating activity on servers are also different
2. AD groups are different, so if I just restore DB from Prod on QA, I will give access to QA to some users.
3. Any other unexpected issue

Is it possible somehow to replace data in all tables (Tables on QA and Prod are identical, difference only in amount of data) from DB backup file and do not touch anything else?

As I understand through Google my only variant is to restore Prod DB on QA server with different name, truncate tables on QA and use SQL MS Wizard but I hope that there are other options.

Comment: UPD: 3rd party compare tools is not an option because server owner is not allow to use it. Only possible options is something free from Microsoft.

Comment: Is this a one off or a regular event? Does it need to be automated? Have you asked this on the [Stack Exchange DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: One time event because our QA data is actual to 2016 and we need to have it fresh. Thanks for the link, i will duplicate ma questions there.

Comment: A possible simple solution is to restore the backups to databases with different names and then use the SSMS import wizard to copy the data.

Comment: I hope to find other options that is why i mentioned it implicitly

Comment: What is wrong with the suggested option? That will give us some kind of idea of what you're after.

Comment: Restoring a database has no effect or relationship to service accounts of the engine. That is a non-issue. You can find scripts to drop all existing users from a database - and then run **your own script** that applies the correct permissions for your QA users. Linked servers, synonyms, 3 and 4 part object names are your problem.

Comment: For people who might need something similar to my problem - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250631/sql-server-update-all-data-in-all-tables-from-backup

Thanks everyone, i understand that there is no some magic technique that i could miss during googling this topic by myself.